# RSS Feed via AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, rss

I am trying to pull posts from my RSS feed into an email via Ampscript.  I have the code correct and it's pulling the right number of stories.  I just want to change the number of stories the script returns to only show items that have been published in the last 7 days.

Here is what I have working now.  It just returns the last 5 stories.

```
%%[Var @xml, @imaged, @titles, @title, @descs, @desc, @links, @link, @cnt
Set @xml = HTTPGet("https://rss.com/feed")
Set @titles = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/title",1)
Set @descs = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/description",1)
Set @links = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//item/link",1)


If RowCount(@titles) > 5 THEN
SET @rows = 5
ELSE
SET @rows = RowCount(@titles)
ENDIF

IF @rows >= 1 THEN
for @cnt = 1 to @rows do
Set @title = Field(Row(@titles,@cnt),"Value")
Set @desc = Field(Row(@descs,@cnt), "Value")
Set @link = Field(Row(@links,@cnt), "Value") ]%%



<head>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
 text-align: left;
}
.auto-style2 {
 color: #000000;
}
.auto-style3 {
 font-size: 14px;
}
.auto-style4 {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<div style="border: 1px solid #444; background-color: #F7F7F7; margin: 0.76em 0; padding: 0.76em;">
<h1 style="font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: bold; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="auto-style4"><a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" alias="%%=v(@title)="%%" title="%%=v(@title)=%% style="color: #000;">
<span class="auto-style2">%%=v(@title)=%%</span></a></h1>
 <div class="auto-style1">
<span style="color: #444; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="auto-style3">%%=v(@desc)=%%</span>
 </div>
</div>
%%[ 
NEXT @cnt 
ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of [examples](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251674/using-ampscript-to-pull-in-rss-feed-content-in-sfmc/252159#252159) of parsing and looping through an RSS feed floating around SFSE.  The example in the official docs is super-fragile and confusing, IMHO.

Here's one that includes a count and date limit:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body, a, input {font-family:sans-serif;}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family:sans-serif">
%%=now(1)=%%

%%[

var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount
set @xml = HTTPGet("https://rss.com/feed", false, 0, @CallStatus)

/* strip out invalid elements if needed */
/* set @xml = Replace(@xml, "dscblog:","") */

output(concat("<br>Call Status: ", @CallStatus))

if indexOf(@xml,"<channel>") > 0 then

  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0)
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

  output(concat("<br>rowCount: ", @rowCount))

  set @rowCount = iif(@rowCount > 5, 5, @rowCount)

  output(concat("<br>rowCount (adj): ", @rowCount))

  if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @pubDate
      var @title
      var @description
      var @link

      set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[",@i,"]/")

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"pubDate"))) > 0 then
          set @pubDate = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"pubDate"),0),1),'Value')
          set @pubDate = SystemDateToLocalDate(@pubDate)
      endif 

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then
          set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then
          set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
      endif

      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then
          set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value')
      endif


      if @pubDate >= DateAdd(Now(1), -14, "D") then

        ]%%

         <h4>%%=v(@title)=%%</h4>
         %%=v(@pubDate)=%%
         <p>
           %%=v(@description)=%%
           <br><a href="%%=redirectto(@link)=%%">%%=v(@link)=%%</a>
         </p>


        %%[

      endif

    next @i

  else

   outputline(concat("<br>no items found"))

  endif

else

  outputline(concat("<br>no XML found"))

endif

]%%

<br><br><br><a href="%%profile_center_url%%">Profile/Preference Center</a>
<br><a href="%%subscription_center_url%%">Subscription Center</a>
<br><a href="%%unsub_center_url%%">One-Click Unsubscribe</a>
<p>This email was sent by:
<b>%%Member_Busname%%</b>
<br>%%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%  %%Member_PostalCode%%  %%Member_Country%%</p>
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: output screenshot]

Comment: The example above is using a 14-day cutoff date since there weren't any posts on that feed in the last 7 days.

Comment: Sorry I know this is now rather old, I'm trying to use this is in a content block but it doesn't seem to load anything. (I've played with different feeds, and tried in a block - which shows the top few lines of the code but nothing else - or within the email which showed nothing.....if anyone sees and has ideas I'd love to get it working?

Comment: Doesn't look like that rss.com feed is valid anymore.  You could just substitute another one -- like https://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed or something.

Comment: Thanks @adam-spriggs sorry I should've said I did replace that feed with a couple of different ones, and I've tried the one you suggest (thank you).  If I create a standalone block,the 'preview' shows part of the code, if I insert it as a snippet in an email the preview shows nothing. Struggling with ideas for troubleshooting!

Comment: Please post a new question that includes the RSS feed and relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, have done so here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360875/rss-feed-via-ampscript-with-earlier-sample-code-failing